# Directions in Android Studio

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to research on how to get the direction from the user's location to the selected marker on android studio(Google Maps). Do you guys have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

1.Use the google map direction api to get direction latlng. [Google direction api](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-how-to-draw-path-between-2-points-on-google-map/)

2.After that you need to draw path on map using polyline.

here is complete tutorial [Link](https://inducesmile.com/android/android-how-to-draw-path-between-2-points-on-google-map/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Google map distance matrix api for finding path from source to destination by given code

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();
        try {
            DirectionsResult result = DirectionsApi.newRequest(getGeoContext())
                    .mode(TravelMode.DRIVING)
                    .origin(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(fromLat, fromLng))
                    .destination(new com.google.maps.model.LatLng(ToLat, ToLng))
                    .departureTime(now)
                    .await();

            addMarkersToMap(result, googleMap);
            addPolyline(result, googleMap);

            if (loader!=null && loader.isShowing()){
                loader.dismiss();
            }
        } catch (ApiException ignored) {
            Log.e("Exception"," "+ignored.getMessage());
        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Exception"," InterruptedException "+e.getMessage());
        }
```

for add marker

```
private void addMarkersToMap(DirectionsResult results, GoogleMap mMap) {
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(results.routes[0].legs[0].startLocation.lat,results.routes[0].legs[0].startLocation.lng))
                .title(from)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(
                new LatLng(results.routes[0].legs[0].endLocation.lat,results.routes[0].legs[0].endLocation.lng))
                .title(to)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
    }
```

Draw polyline and time out for fetching data form google's server

```
private GeoApiContext getGeoContext() {
        GeoApiContext geoApiContext = new GeoApiContext();
        return geoApiContext.setQueryRateLimit(3)
                .setApiKey(getString(R.string.directionsApiKey))
                .setConnectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setReadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setWriteTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

private void addPolyline(DirectionsResult results, GoogleMap mMap) {
        List<LatLng> decodedPath = PolyUtil.decode(results.routes[0].overviewPolyline.getEncodedPath());

        int PATTERN_DASH_LENGTH_PX = 20;
        int PATTERN_GAP_LENGTH_PX = 20;
        PatternItem DASH = new Dash(PATTERN_DASH_LENGTH_PX);
        PatternItem GAP = new Gap(PATTERN_GAP_LENGTH_PX);
        List<PatternItem> PATTERN_POLYGON_ALPHA = Arrays.asList(GAP, DASH);

        mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .geodesic(true)
                .color(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary))
                .width(5)
                .pattern(PATTERN_POLYGON_ALPHA)
                .addAll(decodedPath));
    }
```